# Remove <span> tags, but keep the text?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack to parse a string that contains HTML code.  What I'm trying to do is remove the `<span>` tags, but keep the content between them.  Here's my code, so far:

```
var text = @"<div><span>This is some text.</span>More text here.</div>
<div>I have a question.<span>Hi</span></div>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(text);
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span");
foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
{
   node.Remove();
}
String result = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```

The problem is, the `result` is missing "This is some text." - the text between the `<span>` tags.  How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do?  I realize that `node.Remove` actually removes the entire node, I was just hoping that there is a way I can say `remove.Node`, but keep the content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove that node from parent while keeping the grandchildren.

```
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node,true);
}
```